# selenium ide in multiple checkbox selection when id is always change

Tags: selenium

```
<input id="actionQty_8445901" style="position:absolute" onclick="AddMeToCart(this)" type="checkbox">
```

select multiple check box

```
<input id="actionQty_8445901" style="position:absolute" onclick="AddMeToCart(this)" type="checkbox">

'//input[starts-with(@id,'actionQty_')][1]'
```

am trying this but its working for one check box only

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this xpath to select multiple checkboxes

```
//input[contains(@id,'actionQty')]
```

and also use `findElements()` method to select it

```
List<WebElement> checkElements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'actionQty')]")); 

    for (WebElement check_elem: checkElements) {
          check_elem.click();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath of the element will be like

```
//input[starts-with(@id, 'actionQty_')]
```

then you need to find number of checkbox and click element withinloop
    Then you can get all the checkbox

```
  List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //input[starts-with(@id, 'actionQty_')]")); 

    for (WebElement element: allElements) {
          element.click();
    //do your operation
    }
```

> Hope it will work

Comment: seems you ae correct , but he needs in IDE

Comment: :) oops then its may help to next visitor

Comment: Yes, I have same thinking so posted the answer